# Print 'em goats

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/58375)*

Goats are great. Everybody loves goats.

And they also, for some reason, are an excellent complex ascii art for many languages to have built-ins for. Because of this, I personally feel a catalogue to document just how easily a language can print goats is greatly needed.

### The Challenge

Given an integer input via any means print that many Goats separated by Newlines.

Your Goat for reference is:

```
  ___.
 //  \\
((   ''
 \\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \_\ | |      || |
   \Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/
```

Your particular goat may have more whitespace around it, if required.

### Example

Given `3` on input, Output:

```
  ___.
 //  \\
((   ''
 \\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \_\ | |      || |
   \Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/
  ___.
 //  \\
((   ''
 \\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \_\ | |      || |
   \Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/
  ___.
 //  \\
((   ''
 \\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \_\ | |      || |
   \Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/
```

### The Rules

- You must take an integer input where `0 < input < 256`, and print that many goats.
- Goats may vary in whitespace, as long as the shape of the goat is the same.
- You must submit a full program.
- This is a catalogue, so any language or language version newer than the challenge is acceptable. Like usual, creating a language that prints `N` goats in `0` bytes isn't incredibly creative. Also, as this is a catalogue, no answer will be accepted.
- This is however [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer per language.
- If your language of choice is a trivial variant of another (potentially more popular) language which already has an answer (think BASIC or SQL dialects, Unix shells or trivial Brainfuck-derivatives like Alphuck), consider adding a note to the existing answer that the same or a very similar solution is also the shortest in the other language.

### The Catalogue

*Shamelessly stolen from The Hello World Challenge*

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalogue from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 107765; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 58375; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do we need a newline between each goat?

Comment: Goats must be sequential, and not distorted by previous goats. So yes.

Comment: I would like to vote as a dupe of the rickroll challenge

Comment: I downvoted because this challenge seems to be pandering to languages that have this exact goat art implemented as a built-in. And otherwise it's just copying a fixed string n times, where the string has too little structure to beat hardcoding or general-purpose compression for many languages.

Comment: Given some thought, this was a really bad idea for a challenge fueled by nothing else than the laughs. I've voted to Close it myself.

Comment: I find it kinda funny that both given answers aren't even matching OP's specified output.. Both answers use `"` (double quotes) instead of the 'specified' `'` (single quotes). Also, every line in OP's 'specified' output is missing a space, although I'm assuming that's just a StackExchange formatting issue?

Comment: @ATaco At this moment, none of the answers has a positive score, so you can delete the question if you want to.

Comment: Closevoters: there is nothing unclear about this challenge. Downvote challenges that you dislike - don't close-vote them unless they actually have issues.

Comment: I close voted this myself, free me from my mistakes

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby (2.3), 312 bytes

Hey, at least I didn't use a built-in!

```
n=gets.to_i
puts "
  ___.
 //  \\\\
((   ''
 \\\\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:\";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\\ 
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \\_\\ | |      || |
   \\Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/\n"*n
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by making this a function that accepts a number as an argument Just sayin' ! Returning a string instead of printing would be shorter too, if allowed...

Comment: @LevelRiverSt The challenge requires only a full program

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>194</s>  191 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-3 replacing `b24ị` with `ṃ` (a since-developed atom)

```
“wɦLż8ßȧṛ Ỵ?þġÐ®ạSḍọsñL1⁶ƁṄṫȥẊ`m®Ø⁼ƒ⁺Ė6⁺oHpæİṇµ\ṅṁ⁷V⁶k¡i£}ḣọSƑṭ<ḃṚSØ:kŒxṘıquṂUnƭ⁾DEØẓ×ðH¦ḅċ5pðḳṅ⁶Ḅḍ€®85ɲPp¦Ø0B¥=ẊCƲ<7eØ7ƥ÷8¡ÆḅẎṣṂ(hþẓ]ƲƤȦE¶ƙCɼƭżÆµėṙṾḞ\&O ¬ṆñKmɠ’ṃ“ .¶/\(',6%):";-`YZ|~KLW_”Ṅ¡’
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DZBbSwJRFIX/igSVQVeiFCuCTBAUCqSiMOpFqNQyIiqocLQMCqML1Nh9MKeHUtRS54yDD2ePB@dn7PNHpvOyHjZrfXuxtiKx2JFt8@TLgaUG24Yb3jtfSJ4d2PybhpapwA0toa6EUMtiM7sHleAIl@pMQnKG5LtTQP1yPU5LIHPJYHdc0s2HcaE7/gSoZhnJBa2FkZwjkbjUWBTRKFU2af4EtbzghdgtkuIkamkkTyGQPdH23SES2azs7iNJLWyzIpdasz6QUb@HRyj7qYrauXk1loAyar@CLJConYl6PPVDS@4xqzqfoCrIwzO0MCXaeVl10hUB2cUK0HBTBTICgPo1krz44NyAlkCvsir77Kg@Wmc5r2WwYtuADK2Zj0hySFqovYV75hz0B0kGKoG49cGT4p4WszkGaX0o7OztH@/u83RNDKwvrxyfBoJLazz5KjaiinDatj36Dw)**

#### How?

The 24 distinct characters from which the goat is constructed are:
`` .¶/\(',6%):";-`YZ|~KLW_ ``
where `¶` represents a line feed, and the first character is a space.

A goat may now be thought of as a 277 digit base 24 number, G, where each digit represents the 1-based and mod-24 index of a character in the above list.

The code forms G using base 250, transforms G to a base 24 representation as a list of digits and indexes into the character set. It then repeats an instruction to print the resulting character array and a line feed `n-1` times.

```
a long string of bytes
  |
“...’ṃ“ .¶/\(',6%):";-`YZ|~KLW_”Ṅ¡’ - Main link: n
“...’                               - make G using base 250
      “ .¶/\(',6%):";-`YZ|~KLW_”    - the characters of a goat, ¶ being a line feed
     ṃ                              - base decompression (use the 24 characters as the base 24 digits)
                                  ’ - decrement n to give n-1
                                 ¡  - repeat the previous link n-1 times
                                Ṅ   - print the result and a line feed
```

The only slight complication is that Jelly's base 250 representation is 1-based and the indexing is modular, so when a zero digit is present it will be a 250 digit - the remedy is to reduce the next most significant digit by 1, and repeat if that becomes a zero. (This occasionally will make for shorter code, but not this time.)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 306 bytes

Some slightly compressed goats...

```js
[..."abcdefghijklmnopqrs"].map((c,i)=>s=s.split(c).join(`
 jnk me|h--~~|omLqq
r__pr,; |rr';  \\`.substr(i*2,2)),s=`rl_.a//rss
((r ''assl,
/6 (%)s,
(l/:";nsfllff_
;; :q,:q\`;,qnq\`,\`_k;:n;b':,j,-Ysc;nnb':;j Z/c/ ;,bqnq;'k/ /oq/gg~sq;'a( Krhdks_soodcsZood
i_|iL_|
iW/iLW/
`)&&console.log(s.repeat(prompt()))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 16 bytes

```
"goat " read m C
```

I assume this is the answer you've been waiting for...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@6@Unp9YoqCkUJSamKKQq@D8/78xAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 174 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
▼īj-ηī¤ķJφB╝║α$a3╬ο'Βw)woE;@ē¹█lα.⁶↓!mΙ;┌.}γ§⁹≡r³╝╚wΓδΘργ±:⁾▓√׀⅝╝█%čczgΧMθL`«UΓ║νZ█č└sΩ±⅛mΤCρ2o¦≠]ΖøΙΧ²`žB+9‰κ╚¦¤Ƨ¹≥ΗxƧWJ∞┐∑¹±YEōΟ№Χθ≥⁹~E∞θ<a∙λy⌠s⁹░WP≡Φ╝∆~λ?(l$′Ζŗ=Κ╗2Ψ⁄>τ-‘*
```

vary simple (from the outside)

```
...‘   push that string decompressed
    *  multiply by input
```

I had to chop the goat up into pieces of strings that each when compressed is as small as possible, which then get each compressed and joined together. [more info](http://pastebin.com/UiBSTdkN)

Comment: Chopping up goats? D: that's mean :P

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 306 bytes

`:rep()`'s `io.read()` times.

```
print(([[  ___.
 //  \\
((   ''
 \\__,
/6 (%)\,
(__/:";,;\--____----_
;; :';,:';`;,';,;';`,`_
  ;:,;;';';,;':,';';,-Y\
   ;,;,;';';,;':;';'; Z/
   / ;,';';,;';,;';;'
  / / |';/~~~~~\';;'
 ( K  | |      || |
  \_\ | |      || |
   \Z | |      || |
      L_|      LL_|
      LW/      LLW/
]]):rep(io.read()))
```